# Why is this sentence grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I just encountered this sentence in the novel *David Copperfield* by Charles Dickens. Why is it grammatical? I am just not sure why there could be no conjunction between the two subjects *it* and *he*.

> And, it being low water, he went out with the tide.

Comment: It's a very well-written sentence at that.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman and Kate Bunting, thanks for your advice! But either way, I still feel a bit strange, because usually participial phrases seem to be used to modify a subject rather than a verb(?); also a participial phrase can begin with a pronoun ("it" in this case)? It seems quite different from the participial phrases we usually see: englishsentences.com/participial-phrase

Comment: It's not a participial phrase. "It being low tide" is a 'absolute' construction, a non-finite clause with "it" as subject, and the gerund-participial VP "being low water" as predicate.

Comment: This sentence from the novel *David Copperfield* by Charles Dickens is grammatical because it is a sentence from the novel *David Copperfield* by Charles Dickens. You cannot learn English by questioning native speakers of English. You can only learn English by following their lead.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, noted with thanks! On a different note, may I ask if editors would usually give more leeway to literary writings than formal ones, as to grammatical codes?

Comment: @Jane No, you have misunderstood the very notion of a ‘grammatical code’. Textbooks aimed at English language learners never present the real language in full.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Your point is technically true, but unhelpful; it’s like answering “Why do cars have headlights?” by saying “Because the manufacturers put headlights on them”, rather than “To light up the road ahead when it’s dark”.  It’s a correct answer, but it’s not the only correct answer, and it’s not the answer that’s useful in this situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [*It being low water*], *he went out with the tide.*

The bracketed element is a supplementary non-finite clause.

Since it contains a subject, "it", it belongs to what is known as the **absolute** construction, one that is subordinate in form but with no syntactic link to the main clause "he went out with the tide".

Supplements are not modifiers; rather, they have a semantic 'anchor' that they refer to, in this case the main clause. But there is no explicit indication here of the semantic relation between the supplement and the anchor. This has to be inferred from the content of the clauses and the context.

The natural interpretation here is causal, more specifically 'reason': "He went out with the tide **because** it was low water".

Comment: Thanks BillJ! Your explanation has cleared my confusion!

Comment: The "it" in this sentence is unusual in that it is a pronoun, but unlike most pronouns doesn't take the place of any specific noun.  A similar case would be the sentence: "It is raining."  What is raining?  The sky?  The weather?  You can't really replace the "it" in that sentence with any noun without sounding awkward.

Comment: Yes, it's the so-called 'weather' it. A meaningless dummy pronoun serving the purely syntactic purpose of filling the obligatory subject position.

Comment: Another example is "It's 10pm" or "It's 2019". And these can be used similarly to the original sentence: "It being raining, he grabbed his umbrella."